# What does the last digit of msysgit version mean?

Tags: git, version, windows-server-2008, msysgit

I am running Windows Server 2008, and msysgit. When I run:

`git --version`

on one server it returns

`git version 1.9.4.msysgit.1`

and on another it returns

`git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2`

What is the difference? I searched online and haven't found an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested all 3 versions, and found that:

`git version 1.9.4.msysgit.0` is [Git-1.9.4-preview20140611](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/tag/Git-1.9.4-preview20140611)
`git version 1.9.4.msysgit.1` is [Git-1.9.4-preview20140815](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/tag/Git-1.9.4-preview20140815)
`git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2` is [Git-1.9.4-preview20140929](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/tag/Git-1.9.4-preview20140929)